# Permission denied error when running `git notes` in a Github Action

Tags: git, github, permissions, github-actions

I have the following Github action on my repo. (For the sake of the example,) **I want my workflow to add a [`git notes`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-notes)** on the commit pushed (i.e. run `git notes add -m "foo bar"`).

However, I get the following error:

> fatal: update_ref failed for ref `refs/notes/commits`: cannot lock ref `refs/notes/commits`: **Unable to create `/home/runner/work/repo_name/repo_name/.git/refs/notes/commits.lock`: Permission denied**

What I've tried so far:

- I thought using the `${{ github.token }}` would help, but it isn't.
- I made sure to set “Read and Write permissions” in the repo's Settings/Actions/General/Workflow permissions.
- It is also not a [`chmod +x`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74082530/5433628) issue, as I'm running the command directly.
- Setting the workflow permissions to `write-all` (as [suggested by Azeem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75204326/permission-denied-error-when-running-git-notes-in-a-github-action?noredirect=1#comment132709149_75204326) doesn't solve it either.

Could this be a concurrency issue?

---

Github Action YAML file:

```yaml
name: Notes

on:
  workflow_dispatch:

permissions: write-all

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0
          token: ${{ github.token }}
      - name: Add git notes
        id: git-notes
        run: |
          git config user.name "Github Actions"
          git config user.email "bot@github.actions"
          git notes add -m "foo bar"
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ github.token }}
```

Log:

```
 Run git config user.name "Github Actions"
  git config user.name "Github Actions"
  git config user.email "bot@github.actions"
  git notes add --allow-empty -m "foo bar"
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
  env:
    GITHUB_TOKEN: ***
Removing note for object HEAD
fatal: update_ref failed for ref 'refs/notes/commits': cannot lock ref 'refs/notes/commits': Unable to create '/home/runner/work/marion_test_notes/marion_test_notes/.git/refs/notes/commits.lock': Permission denied
Error: Process completed with exit code 128.
```

Comment: You're already configuring `token` so no need to set the env var `GITHUB_TOKEN`. Looks like it's a token permissions issue. See: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/assigning-permissions-to-jobs.

Comment: Thanks @Azeem for your suggestion! FYI, I added `permissions: write-all` to the workflow, but the error remains the same.

Comment: Right. I'll try to reproduce it on my side and update you later.

Answer (score 1):

Just tried to reproduce your scenario with this workflow:

```yaml
name: git_notes

on:
  workflow_dispatch:

permissions:
  actions: write

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          fetch-depth: '0'
          token: ${{ github.token }}
      - name: Add git notes
        id: git-notes
        run: |
          git config user.name "Github Actions"
          git config user.email "bot@github.actions"
          git notes add -m "foo bar"
          git notes show
```

But, it's working fine.

Here's the workflow run (note is verified with `git notes show`):

[image: workflow run]

---

As the issue doesn't seem to be with the workflow, you might to need check if there are any branch protection rules hindering this on your side.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I do appreciate! I'll work from your workflow and see what makes mine fail.

Comment: Thanks to your “minimal working example”, and after further troubleshooting, I've been able to devise a workflow that's robust enough for my use case. It's detailed in my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [Azeem's minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75209187/5433628), I have troubleshot my issue.

In my case, the error was generated because **the commit had a note already** (added by a separate step of the workflow).

---

Building on Azeem's solution, I faced further issues that made the workflow fail, such as:

- the commit has a note already (initial issue),
- the note added is not “pushed upstream” — i.e. it disappears once the workflow ends, instead of being permanently added to the history,
- other commits in the history have git notes already (but these are not synced by simply using the `actions/checkout` step),
- the workflow fails if run a second time.

Long story short, here is a workflow that robustly adds a `git notes` on the head checked out:

```yaml
name: git notes

on:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  add_git_note:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0
          token: ${{ github.token }}
      - name: Add a git note
        run: |
          git fetch origin refs/notes/*:refs/notes/*
          git config user.name "github-actions"
          git config user.email "bot@github.com"
          git notes add --allow-empty --force --message="foo bar"
          git notes show
          git push origin refs/notes/*
```

Explanations:

- `git fetch origin refs/notes/*:refs/notes/*`: “Pull” the `git notes` already existing in the repo (otherwise, it you'll get a conflict when trying to push your new note back upstream),
- `git config`: Create `git` ID, which is required to add a note and push upstream,
- `git notes add`: Add your note

  - `--allow-empty`: In case your message is empty (e.g. has been generated by a previous step of the workflow),
  - `--force`:  In case you run the workflow again (so the commit has a note already). Note that (obviously), **this overwrites any already existing `git notes`**. You can otherwise have a look at [`git notes append`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-notes).
- `git notes show`: Cheap logging
- `git push origin refs/notes/*`: Push the note back upstream (i.e. to the git repo), so that it survives the end of the workflow.

---

<sub>**References:**</sub>

- <sub>[`git notes` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-notes)</sub>
- <sub>[How to sync](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18269026/5433628) (i.e. “pull” and push) `git notes` with upstream</sub>
- <sub>[git notes | Enhance Git Commit Messages with Notes](https://initialcommit.com/blog/git-notes)</sub>
- <sub>[Git Notes: git's coolest, most unloved­ feature](https://tylercipriani.com/blog/2022/11/19/git-notes-gits-coolest-most-unloved-feature/)</sub>